# Can I add iOS 7 support to an app that was released as an iOS 8 app only

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've been searching through documentation for a while and I can't really find it. My question is very simple:

If I submit an app that works on **iOS 8 only**, will I be able to add a **iOS 7 support with an update**?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Just change the deployment target and make sure your code or features that you advertise work accordingly with iOS7 API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to do the following:

> 1. Go to your project target's settings "General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target" to iOS 7.x.
> 2. Test your application on iOS 7.x device and make sure your application is not crashing and working as expected. If there are iOS
>      8.x only API's used in your code, you need to switch to API's for iOS 7.x at runtime.

Note: Since you are about to add the support for iOS 7.x, avoid using the deprecated API's. This will save your life later on when these deprecated API's are gone.